# UIScrollview behavior like UIImagePicker scroll view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to create custom uiimagepicker with image sliding behavior like UIImagePicker, but cant find out the way to set bouncing mode to bounce back or forward when i stop sliding at the middle of one image.

Comment: Can you put some code that you tried?

Comment: Did you try Tree20 Framework?

Answer (score 1):

```
int moveY = reckView.frame.origin.y - parentScrollView.contentOffset.y - parentScrollView.contentInset.top;

if (moveY > 0) {
    [parentScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, parentScrollView.contentOffset.y + moveY - reckView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
} else {
    [parentScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, parentScrollView.contentOffset.y + moveY) animated:YES];
}
```

I think this code will bring you close to your solution. Note that, this will not bounce, instead it will slowly adjust scrollView position.

Here,

parentScrollView is the scrollView.

reckView is the view which contains thumb image.